# ReadyNAS 3200 Taking a Long Time to boot

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage, readynas

I have a ReadyNAS 3200 that locked up on me. I could web into it, I could see the files on it via CIFS, but it would not allow me to access existing, or edit/create new files. I would get an error from Windows that I don't have permission. I also has had a couple backup VMs on that server, and when I would try to power them on, it would tell me the files are locked/read-only.

So I rebooted the system via the web interface, and I checked the box to preform a file system check on reboot.

The system went down for a reboot, and over 8 hours had not come backup. I hard reset it and told it to skip the file check, and it came back up, but went un-responsive again after a few hours.

I brought it back down, and have it doing a file system check again, at first it show a ton of disk activity, but it is not showing much at all for disk activity, and is not coming back up. It has been two hours.

Also, when I force it up there is no hardware problems reported by the unit.

Any ideas on my next step?

Comment: Contact your vendor? It sounds like an issue you won't be able to fix without the vendor's help.

Comment: +1 for contact the vendor... I'd either do what @NathanC said or give it the time to run the file system check.  If after a full day it hasn't moved then your best bet is probably a warranty return or vendor repair.

Comment: It is no longer under warranty... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Netgear and even though I was out of support contract with them, they did take the information I had gathered, and came to a fairly certain conclusion that the filesystem somehow got hosed on the NAS. Which is possible, as we had a very long power failure a couple weeks ago that initially made the NAS act up.

The solution - complete Factory Restore and recreation of the filesystem on the device.